# Is there a way for me to draw an image to my screen without it being on a window?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to draw an image to my screen like with [CustomDesktopLogo](http://customdesktoplogo.wikidot.com/download), but for some reason, every solution I find doesn't work how I imagined.

Comment: The reason for that is maybe you do not know how your operating system is working

Comment: I know how my operating system works, and also, I managed to figure it out.

Comment: A person made a video for drawing colors to your screen using Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(IntPtr.Zero); then you do g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Rectangle(40, 10, 50, 50));

Comment: Except with that approach, you have to continuously redraw your logo since other windows will "erase" what you have done.  This is why you should draw to your OWN window.  You can make your form topmost and transparent and then change the [REGION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.region?view=netcore-3.1) of your form so that it literally only exists where your logo is (a non-rectangular form).  You can also make your form "pass through" with respect to clicks by setting the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag in CreateParams().

Answer (score 1):

in windows, if you want to draw on any place, you must to get its `HDC`, In C# you must use `Graphics` instead of using HDC with every draw method, And you can get HDC From `HWND` only, and if you are using `Graphics.FromHWND()` it's use `GetDC(IntPtr HWND)`, so you can get HDC From HWND, and Desktop HWND is Zero.

```
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromHWND(IntPtr.Zero);
// Use gfx to draw
```

Comment: This answer looks nice.  Im a bit confused, that you mentioned HDC (FromHdc) and then using FromHWND. Please elaborate a bit more.